# How do i make my discord bot select a message from a list of phrases and send a random selected phrase from that list to a specific user?

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

> I already have this code but it doesn't work correctly. When I change the message for a specific phrase it works but it don't work when I try to grab a random item from the list made before.

---

```py
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We are live as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('&hello'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello There')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
        
    if message.author.id == 295365551499247618:
      list = ["Oye callate","Quien te pregunto", "A nadie le importa", "Muerete", "Vete pa la pinga","Callate"]
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(list))

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: what does "doesn't work correctly" mean? Are you getting an error? The code as written will error out when author id is not 295365551499247618  because `list` never gets initialized appropriately.  As a side note, `list` is a python builtin, you should use a different variable name or it will shadow the builtin and can create harder to track down errors

Comment: Please indent `await message.channel.send(random.choice(list))` to be under the if condition

Answer (score 1):

I can see two problems with your code

1. The variable `list` is a built-in feature of python.
2. The `await message.channel.send(random.choice(list))` is not indented inside the if statement.

This code should work:

```
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return
            
        if message.author.id == 295365551499247618:
          msg_list = ["Oye callate","Quien te pregunto", "A nadie le importa", "Muerete", "Vete pa la pinga","Callate"]
          await message.channel.send(random.choice(msg_list))
    
    client.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is quite an easy fix, simply change `await message.channel.send(random.choice(list)` to `await message.channel.send(random.choice(msg_list)`. Python won't recognise list as that specific list, you'll still have to point it by using msg_list.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the list out of the if thing. If the list is in the if thing it doesnt work.
Thats because when you define a variable in a if thing you cant use it after the if thing because it is possible that the variable doesnt exist.

Or you can do the sending message part in the if thing.